# cursor is coming by default under password when page loads field how to resolve

Tags: javascript

Please help me to solve this , i have a page that have some validation in form
when you load the page the cursor automatically lands into password field which is become a hack for me please help me .

https://mobulous.app/healthapp/doctorlogin

[image]

Comment: Hi & welcome to the SO. Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have line which forces password to get focus: at line 136

[image]

Comment: Thanks i have removed this , but still focusing on password field , don't know why

Comment: May be you should try once in private window or just clear cache.

Comment: i have tried this , clearing browser cache and checked in private mode.. noting happens..

Comment: check for yourself on different machine, for time being a [remote one](https://www.browserling.com/browse/win/7/chrome/65/https%3A%2F%2Fmobulous.app%2Fhealthapp%2Fdoctorlogin)

Answer (score 0):

You have a code in the below JS file which focuses inputPassword id on **$(document).ready(function(){...})**:

https://mobulous.app/healthapp/public/assets/js/custome.js

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inputPassword").focus();

    $("#pwchecknext").click(function(){
        if ($("#pwchecknext").is(":checked"))
        {
            $(".oppwasconf").clone()
            .attr("type", "text").insertAfter(".oppwasconf")
            .prev().remove();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".oppwasconf").clone()
            .attr("type","password").insertAfter(".oppwasconf")
            .prev().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

You need to remove this <del>**$("#inputPassword").focus();**</del> to not to autofocus password on reload.

Comment: Thanks i have removed this , but still focusing on password field , don't know why

Comment: You need to clear the browser cache. It is working correctly for me now.